# Ключи запуска консольного приложения

Tags: c#

Например в утилите ***ping*** есть свои аргументы. `ping -n 1 localhost`. Как такое реализовать в консольном приложении? **Именно ключи, а не args в Main.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь библиотеками, которые упрощают обработку аргументов командной строки, переданных приложению. Одной из популярных и удобных в использовании является [Command Line Parser Library](http://commandline.codeplex.com/).

Вот пример ее использования:

```
class Options {
  //как в примере с ping
   [Option('n', "lines",
        Default = 5U,
        SetName = "bylines",
        HelpText = "Lines to be printed from the beginning or end of the file.")]
    uint? Lines { get; set; }

  [Option('r', "read", Required = true,
    HelpText = "Input file to be processed.")]
  public string InputFile { get; set; }

  [Option('v', "verbose", DefaultValue = true,
    HelpText = "Prints all messages to standard output.")]
  public bool Verbose { get; set; }

  [ParserState]
  public IParserState LastParserState { get; set; }

  [HelpOption]
  public string GetUsage() {
    return HelpText.AutoBuild(this,
      (HelpText current) => HelpText.DefaultParsingErrorsHandler(this, current));
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
  var options = new Options();
  if (CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options)) {
    // пример доступа
    if (options.Verbose) Console.WriteLine("Filename: {0}", options.InputFile);
  }
}
```

## UPD#1 Как подключить?

В [Package Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console) консоли выполняем команду:

```
Install-Package CommandLineParser
```

Comment: Хорошо, а как его подключить в проект?

Comment: @frago добавил upd#1

Comment: Добавил пакет из менеджера nuget (пишу в Rider). Вот [скриншот](https://snag.gy/0hYU5I.jpg)

Comment: upd: решено переходом на последний релиз.